# Add a number to a vector inside a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list like this

```
x <- list(a=1:10, b="Good morning", c="Hi")
```

If I type `x[1]` or `x[c("a")]` I get the numbers 1 to 10 of the vector

I want to add 5 to each element of the vector a inside the list x.

I tried

```
x[1] + 5 #didn't work

x[c("a")] + 5 #didn't work
```

I tried a few other things I found on google and they didn't work

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few solutions:

```
> x <- list(a=1:10, b="Good morning", c="Hi")
> x[["a"]] + 5
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
> x[[1]] + 5
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
> x$a + 5
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

The problem with your approach is that `[]` is the syntax to index vectors, but `x` is a list and not a vector. To get the an element of a list, you need to use `[[]]`. By using `x[1]` you get a sublist whose single element is a vector instead of getting a vector.

**Addition in response to comment asking how to update the original list:**

In R you can use the same syntax to retrieve values from and object and to assign values to that object.

```
> x$a <- x$a + 5
> x
$a
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

$b
[1] "Good morning"

$c
[1] "Hi"
```

Any combination of the different possible syntaxes would have worked, too:

```
x[["a"]] <- x[[1]] + 5
```

Comment: Thanks ! I can't update the original list  because lists are immutable right ? Nope, got it.,